# Get full URL of web page with php

Tags: php, url, sha

I have been asked to build a program that measures the time it takes to enter certain web page , the problem is that the URLs are the same as they are masked with SHA how could get the URL's real?

Example:

https://10.12.0.1/Apps/WebObjects/AccountManagement.woa/2/wo/**HZrjmzCtLPIMMQoew742x0**/0.4

It's the only number to changed.

Thanks!

Comment: do u want to get current full url addres?

Comment: yes, but is a external page (It isn't my server), I login and ever the URL is similar to the top, don't see the really  URL in the navegation.